# Docker - PHP composer - private repository

Tags: docker, ssh, composer-php, repository, private

I've cloned a new project on OSX, inside which I have `composer.json` with a reference to a private repository.

I want to use the official Docker composer image, to install all dependencies. Everything works, but the problem occurs with a private repository, because of course, composer container doesn't have a SSH key installed in it. Reasonable.

Could somebody explain to me what would be the 'accurate' way to install the PHP dependency from my private repo?

I've read on the official docs (https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/composer/), where they say:

`When you need to access private repositories, you will either need to share your configured credentials, or mount your ssh-agent socket inside the running container:`

I'm on OSX, so the mounting part won't work as I've found out during my research.

I also read that the 'Docker' way is to not have the SSH part on the composer image. In other words, only one process per container.

So another way I found is to run a separate SSH server, but I'm not sure how this works actually. Supposedly I would connect through it into the `composer` container?

If anyone had some experience with this kind of problem, please share your thoughts.

I'm sorry if I left something out, if I did, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you use SSH agent on a Mac? That would be the best way of solving your problem

Comment: The thing is, this is a script that is setting up the project. 

I don't want to force a developer to have php and composer installed on their system, but the install script should install the dependencies using the composer container.

So far everything was working excellent, except this tiny issue :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. In order to install from a private repo, as you said, you need SSH authentication. You can use, again as you said, SSH agent sharing to make the container "SSH aware". You also said that you can't use that in Mac OS X. Could you clarify this last claim?

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried the method suggested on official docker composer image page : `docker run --rm --interactive --tty --volume $PWD:/app --volume $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-auth.sock --env SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-auth.sock composer install`, but I get `Host key verification failed. `. After some googling, I stumbled upon articles like this one https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/410, where it says it's not possible to forward ssh agent, on OSX.

Comment: I don't know if the agent will work or not, but the error you are having "Host key verification failed" has nothing to do with authentication, yet. Check http://linuxcommando.blogspot.it/2008/10/how-to-disable-ssh-host-key-checking.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll check this out.